# Tweak of DispatcherServlet settings web.xml - need alternative BeanInjection approach

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to tweak the definition of my dispatcher servlet in my web.xml.

I had everything working perfectly using the settings below...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

But now I am trying to tweak the settings to be the following and I get errors...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
           /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The error I get is a null pointer exception for one of my filter classes because in that class I do the following...

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

Where @Qualifier("sessionRegistry") is defined somewhere in classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-application-context.xml. So what I was doing was grabbing a bean defined in spring-application-context.xml using a qualifier but I can no longer do that with the new DispatcherServlet definition inside web.xml.

Can someone suggest to me an alternative method of injecting the sessionRegistry bean defined in my spring-application-context.xml that will work.

SessionRegistry is defined in spring-application-context.xml like this...

```
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

**updated**
I have a ContextLoaderListener defined in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here is a link to my full web.xml...

http://pastebin.com/fJXwGNgn

thanks

Comment: Does the filter class fall in the reach of the component scanning of `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`?

Comment: There should be nothing preventing you from doing so. Do you have a `ContextLoaderListener` registered else your `spring-application-context.xml` is pretty useless.

Comment: I don't think there is a link in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml to the filter class. The beans are defined in spring-application-context.xml. How would I create the link between mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and spring-application-context?

Comment: Hi, Since looking into this further I've found I was doing something wrong. The sessionRegistry was defined in the root context and so was the bean where the autowire annotation was used. From my newfound understanding it does not make sense to use annotations because both beans where defined in the application-context.xml. So the dependencies should be injected via the xml